# Выполнение процессорм несуществующих инструкций

Tags: ассемблер, процессор

Здравствуйте! Для начала хочу прояснить как я понимаю работу процессора, поправьте, если что-то не так. Грубо: Процессору даётся команда считывания инструкции, вводиться сама инструкция, её код(ну из 0 и 1), потом процессор сопоставляет введённую инструкцию с инструкциями, записанными в нём,  получает операнды(если такие есть), и делает, то что должна делать эта инструкция.

**Вопрос:**

Возможно ли как-то скомпилировать програму с не валидной инструкцией, заставить процессор перейти к ней. Если да, то что произойдёт? Просто сверит, не найдёт соответствия и всё?Предусмотрено ли такая ситуация?

Архитектура не важна, ARM,X86

Comment: Помнится, как одна программка "для своих" на работе вдруг не заработала. Пошел  разбираться. Было это во времена 386 процессоров, компилировал я тогда с ключиком 286, но ведь нашлась в бюджетной конторе древняя XT'шка! :) Так что - скомпилировать с невалидной инструкцией - как два... байта переслать.

Comment: Архитектура тут как раз важна, в разных архитектурах совершенно по-разному всё это делается. Что касается современных (мощных) процессоров, то у них как правило есть набор исключений, одно из которых как раз "неверная инструкция".

Answer (score 7):

В случае несуществующей инструкции возникает исключение (прерывание) с определённым номером (int 6). В стеке хранится адрес возврата. По этому адресу можно "вручную" програмно выполнить иснтрукцию, сдвинуть ip-адрес возврата, и сделать возврат iret (для x86) на следущюю инструкцию. Таким образом делалось, к примеру, эмуляция сопроцессора. При этом нужно точно знать как выполнить инструкцию. Для процессора ARM режим исключения (ловушка) по несуществующей инструкции возможно тоже есть. Для ARM7 вектор [0x4](http://www.gaw.ru/html.cgi/txt/doc/micros/arm/arh_7dtmi/exclude.htm#8)

Что будет если встретилась такая инструкция:

1. Если сделать пустой обработчик -  процессор повиснет.
2. Как вариант можно написать "программа выполнила недопустимую инструкцию и будет закрыта" (многие версии Windows так делают).
3. Если есть эмуляция - команду выполнит эмулятор

---

Теперь о том зачем эмуляция команд. 
Случай с x86 486. Там есть замечательная команда bswap eax;  которую не поддерживает 386. Зараннее зная что эту команду нужно выполнять, мы пишем программу, вешаем её на прерывание по несуществующей команде, где если data[(e)ip] = код_bswap то выполняем обмен внутри eax. Потом смещаем (e)ip на длинну команды делаем возврат. Как вариант можно эмулировать mmx расширение. Можно на intel эмулировать команды amd и наоборот. Но это будет касатся только даной платформы.

Теперь об АРМ. Есть программа для ARM7, теоретически её можно выполнять на ARM6 если знать все недостающие команды в этой платформе и реализовать их выполнение в виде процедур.

---

О  кроссплатформенности. Команды для x86 и команды ARM никогда по кодам не пересекутся. Поэтому обработка несуществующих команд будет для каждого процессора своя. Да, можно с помощью `#define` разграничить и заточить с++ на две три разные платформы реализовав решение в разных файлах - да, и возможно как-то обьеденить всё в `proc1(PTR * addr, REGS * reg)` но даже регистры у процессоров разные.  Поэтому смысла особого в этом нет. Для каждой платформы процессора прийдётся писать свою неповторимую эмуляцию, которая учёт особенности именно этой конкретной архитектуры.

---

Возможно ли как-то скомпилировать програму с не валидной инструкцией? Ответ да, если у процессора существуют такие (есть процессоры где всё пространство инструкций заполнено и таковых нет, как правило RISC архитектуры). это будет только тогда, когда ПО собирается под одну версию ахитектуры, а выполняется на другой  (например собрали под 486 а выполняется на 286, или собрали под Pentium-III, а выполняем на Pentium-II), или намерено генерируем код не под ту платформу под которую собрано (с помощью `__emit__` или выполняем команды в массиве). Но обычно так не делают. Что б программа заработала, на уровне ядра OS делают эмуляцию. И последнее - емуляция значительно замедляет выполнение:).

В контексте исключительных ситуаций процессора применяется три понятия, которые часто в литературе могут быть как "синонимами" так и разными понятиями (что иногда вызывает путаницу): *interrupt* (int сокращённо) - прерывание (как по исключению так и нет), *trap* - ловушка (имеется ввиду исключительной ситуации), *exception* - исключение.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, то, что вы говорите, описывает логику _одного_ процессора (судя по инструкции `iret` — Intel x86). Мне не кажется, что есть универсальное правило.

Comment: @Vlad признаю, я кроссплатформенное решение вопроса написать не могу. Процессор x86 где `iret` возврат из прерывания. Разные процессоры обрабатывают примерно одинаково, только "регистр" возврата может хранится по-разному. У одних в стеке, у некоторых возможно в регистрах. Не все процессоры поддерживают несуществующую команду (у некоторых такой нету). Но за ARM ничего сказать не могу.

Comment: Я думаю, кроссплатформенный ответ и не возможен, процессоров слишком много :-/ Возможно, имеет смысл указать в ответе, к какому процессору/каким процессорам относится ваш ответ.

Comment: Скорее произойдёт Exception, а не прерывание.

Comment: @0andriy касательно архитектуры x86 обработка прерывания и исключения одинаково реализованы в реальном режиме, и иногда даже приравниваются, причём `iret` возвращает как с прерывания так и из исключения.  Небольшое отличие есть. Пожалуй да, скорее исключение.

Comment: @nick_n_a, насколько я понимаю, прерывание -- всего лишь частный случай исключения. Поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь.