# Проверяет ли операционная система перед запуском исполняемого файла содержащиеся в нем инструкции?

Tags: ассемблер, ос

Проверяет ли условная операционная система (Linux, Windows) перед запуском исполняемого файла содержащиеся в нем инструкции? То есть, если в исполняемом файле по той или иной причине окажется неподдерживаемая инструкция, получим ли мы ошибку на этапе запуска, или же во время выполнения?

Comment: AFAIK, во время выполнения.  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/603053/195342

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выполнение процессорм несуществующих инструкций](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603053/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Answer (score 6):

Нет, такой проверки нет. Хотя бы по той причине, что может быть какой-то неверный `jmp` прямо в середину команды, и вся проверка насмарку. А проверять все возможные переходы, в том числе и те, которые при выполнении не выполнятся? Да и замедление при выполнении было бы очень заметным.

Обычно при попадании на неверную инструкцию генерируется исключение (не путать с исключениями С++), обработчик которого либо завершит программу, либо может как-то разумно обработать ситуацию (если его пишет автор программы).